# Parse objects, roles vs relations

Tags: swift, parse-platform, relationship

In a parse app I am currently building, you enter the app and create an event, you also can choose events in a collection view which you would like to attend.

Would it be better to use roles or relations in this case? I added two relations to the "Events" class synced with _User, one called "Creator" and the other "Attendee" but I'm not sure if this was the best way to go about it.

I also would need to be adding the users to an attendee array at the same time to display how many users will be attending the event as well, I suppose I would have to do this separately though.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: A relation is a super-powered array, so you are ok with that. As for the creator, since it will always be just one, you don't need a relation field, but rather a simple pointer field.

Comment: Keep an attendee relation but also a count variable